# Getting undefined reference when using OpenGL in Geany

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, linux-mint, geany

This is my first time using OpenGL. I am using Linux Mint. My editor is Geany. I have installed freeglut3 and the development package. But I can run any of code.

Whenever I try to build any of my code it is saying that undefined reference. I have searched the web and also looked at so and there saying and some are saying add these to my linker flags, "-lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW". I don't know how to do that, I am very new.

I usually use Windows. But now I have to use Linux and Geany. Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

int main()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: show the compilation command used by `geany` (*Build -> Set Build Commands* menu). Notice that order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a lot. Or better yet try to compile on the command line in a terminal.

Comment: thanks i have solved the problem, all you have to do is add -lglut -lGL -lGLU in build->set build commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by adding

```
-lglut -lGL -lGLU
```

to compile command in Build->Set Build Commands menu